# Boundedness of $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-x}+\frac{1}{n-2x}+\dots+\frac{1}{n-(n-1)x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $0\leq x\le 1$, and $n$ a positive integer. Define the function

$$f(n,x)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-x}+\frac{1}{n-2x}+\dots+\frac{1}{n-(n-1)x}.$$

For which $x$ is the sum bounded by a constant for arbitrarily large $n$?

If $x=0$, this is $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}=1$, a constant. If $x=1$, it is $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-1}+\dots+\frac{1}{1}$, a divergent sum. The question is what happens in between.

As mfl wrote, the sum is bounded above by $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Is it also true that the sum converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: Does the formula $$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{1-x\frac{k}n}$$ ring any bell?

Comment: Someone said Riemann sums? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-x}+\frac{1}{n-2x}+\dots+\frac{1}{n-(n-1)x}\le  \frac{n}{n-(n-1)x}\underbrace{\nearrow}_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1-x}$$ for $0<x<1.$

Comment: To get the sum of the series use the expression given by @Did. It is a Riemann sum.