# Upper bound for $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-x}+\frac{1}{n-2x}+\dots+\frac{1}{n-(n-1)x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $0<x<1$ and $n$ a positive integer. Define the function
$$f(n,x)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n-x}+\frac{1}{n-2x}+\dots+\frac{1}{n-(n-1)x}.$$

It can be shown ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899815/boundedness-of-frac1n-frac1n-x-frac1n-2x-dots-frac1n-n-1x)) that $f(n,x)\leq\frac{1}{1-x}$. Moreover, when seen as a Riemann sum we can see that for large $n$, the sum approaches to $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xy}dy=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$.

Is there a better upper bound (only in terms of $x$) than $\frac{1}{1-x}$? The fact that the sum approaches $-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$ by computing this integral doesn't show that this is an upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the way that the bound $-\frac{\log(1- x)}{x}$ is obtained. Your sum can be interpreted as a (left) Riemann sum for the function $\frac{1}{1-xy}$, as a function of $y$. Since this function is increasing on $[0,1]$, the left Riemann sum is always a lower bound for the integral. Therefore, $-\frac{\log(1- x)}{x}$ is the lowest upper bound that is valid for all $n$.

Note that this bound is specifically better than $\frac{1}{1-x}$:

[image]